# How to set dynamic titles in one page template embedding different pages inside the body tag - PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, title

According to single page template structure there's only one file called `index.php` that embeds pages in it using PHP function `include_once()` inside the body tag against the query string `$_GET['page']`

```
<?php $page = $_GET['page']; ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         <!-- title needs to update according to page here -->
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php  require_once MC_ROOT.'/pages/'.$page.'.php'; // page content goes here like: <div> [CONTENT], <h1> [PRODUCT TITLE] </h1> </div> etc... ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

How do i set dynamic titles inside `<title></title>` tags which comes before for each page? Pages are supposed to be `home, product, contact, about` etc. Please suggest any best practice. Thank you

Comment: Add parameter to get ?

Comment: actually urls are like: `/index.php?page=home` or `index.php?page=product` or `/index.php?page=about`. each page is being embedded inside the body tags of `index.php` file getting value from query string. seems simple but i guess structure is not good.

Comment: Can you add a parameter like /index.php?page=home&title=test ? Then you could just get the 'dynamic' title for your page. Or you could do it in javascript, setting a hidden html tag in your page and then modify the title with hidden html tag content

Comment: No, all URL's are rewritten with `ids` and `page` values. like: `/product/232` here `product` is a `paqe` and `232` is an `id`. this `product` page contains product title inside it from database `$row->title` that needs to be set as a page title. Titles should not be passed as parameter.

Comment: then javascript is a correct option

Comment: avoiding javascript method. it might not be good for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pars_url(This function parses a URL)

for exam
if you address like this

```
$url = "http://www.ibm.com/product?id=1";
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
////echo product /////
```

OR

```
$url = 'http://www.ibm.com/product/il.php?id=value';
$var  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$var  = explode('/', $url);
echo $var[3];
///echo product////
```

OR

```
$url = 'http://www.ibm.com/aboutUs.php';
$var  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$var  = explode('/', $url);
$var = str_replace(".php","",$var[3]);
echo $var;
///echo aboutUs////
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but `product.php` file _(which is being embedded in index.php file inside `<body>` tag)_ is fetching product title `$row->title` from database. this title i would like to use as PAGE TITLE in `index.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You can include a title-page mapping:

mapping.php

```
$mapping = [
 'home' => 'Welcome on my homepage',
 'product' => ['242' => 'My fidget Spinner'] 
];

$title = '';
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
 if(isset($mapping[$_GET['page']])){
   $title = $mapping[$_GET['page']];
 }
}

if(isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['id'])){
 if(isset($mapping[$_GET['page']][$_GET['id']])){
   $title = $mapping[$_GET['page']][$_GET['id']];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, how do i set `'My fidget Spinner` _a mysql fetched value_ in `product.php` file? and `mapping.php` file should be included in `index.php` file before `<title>` tags? please correct if it's wrong.

Comment: So if your Product title Comes from database you can avoid the mapping for Products and just get the right title by the given ID from your database

Answer (score 0):

you should use ob_start :

```
ob_start();
$header=MC_ROOT.'/pages/'.$page.'.php';
include($header);
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%","NEW TITLE",$buffer);
echo $buffer;
```